How to get hexes on a line on hex grid but give 2 options when in middle of 2 hexes
I think the title is pretty self-explanatory, but I will provide some extra info so you understand what I mean better.
Basically I have a hex grid, and am trying to get the hexes on a line from one point to another in cube coords (where I got the algorithm from).
The problem with the current algorithm is that it just rounds the values. I also tried both flooring and ceiling the values if its *.5 and the doing some weird distance calculations, but to no avail. I got it to kindaaaa work but there were very many super-weird edge-cases.
Also I'm using flat top hexes if that changes anything.
To the person who will solve this incredible mystery, I thank you very much in advance, I already spend half a day trying to solve this.
(Maybe an adaptation of Bresenham's algorithm)

